# Function in Kendo template: Angular JS1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a currency column like this :

```
{
  field: 'INVOICE_AMOUNT_ORIGINAL',
  title: $translate.instant('invoiceAmount'),
  format: '{0:n}',
  template: '#= currency(dataItem.INVOICE_AMOUNT_ORIGINAL)#',
  headerTemplate: '{{ \'invAmount\' | translate }}',
  attributes: {
    style: 'text-align: right;'
  },
  width: 115
}
```

and i have a function

```
function currency(currencyValue) {
  kendo.culture('de-DE'); 
  kendo.toString(currencyValue, 'c2'); 
}
```

But even after applying proper syntax in template, the function doesn't get called.

I am trying to pass values such as de-DE or en-US in template via function so that anytime any user set its preference to it, it changes dynamically in kendo grid,

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put function currency in $scope. I don't know how your template is working, but I think the problem is that your template field doesn't see the function.

```
$scope.currency = function(currencyValue) {
    kendo.culture('de-DE'); 
    kendo.toString(currencyValue, 'c2');
};
```

Another option is to use expressions in field like you did in headerTemplate.

```
template: '#= {{currency(dataItem.INVOICE_AMOUNT_ORIGINAL)}}#'
```